# Twitter Retweet iMacro

Tags: twitter, imacros

My Specs:
OS: Windows 10
Firefox Version: 47.0.1
iMacro Version: 8.9.7

(I hope that's all you need?)

My Problem:

I'm trying to make a Twitter Retweet iMacro, and the weirdest thing is happening. So here's a Tweet:

https://twitter.com/jjuanusa/status/749885664204816384

In order to retweet this sonofabitch you have to click twice. First you click the Retweet icon there, and then a little popup appears, where you click Retweet, and the tweet gets retweeted.

My problem is with the first click that has to be made.

Now, for this tweet (having 10 retweets at the moment), this line of code works:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Retweet<SP>10
```

However, I need a line that works universally for any tweet. I have tried the following until now:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Retweet<SP>*

TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Retweet*

TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Retweet

TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:*

TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:

TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TITLE:Retweet
```

NONE works. WTF? The asterisk * is supposed to be a universal switcher, and should have worked!!

Can anyone help? I can't believe I'm stuck on this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Retweet* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:{{!EXTRACT}}
```